# Developing a Decoder Extension in PHP

Tags: php

Recently I'm programming a website and I want to prevent my source code from being seen.

I tried famous Guards like Zend or ionCube but I understood that Encoded Code can be decoded easily.

Now I want to develop an Extension to Decode the code at runtime.
I have a Problem.
When the extension runs and the code processes how to return the code to php to be processed?

Comment: Who told you that Zend/ionCube encoded code can be decoded easily? Also, developing a robust encoder/decoder is a *massive* task and probably requires intimate knowledge of the PHP engine. What is your use case exactly? Are you looking to distribute your web site?

Comment: You could always compile it instead - try the HipHop PHP compiler. See http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/358

Comment: Yes, I want to distribute it. It's a cms not a website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to write an extension.  You will need to know C.

Refer to: http://devzone.zend.com/article/1021 and http://www.php.net/manual/en/internals2.php

Comment: Well, I read them but I want to know how to return the code to php

Comment: I mean, I have a function for example RunCode() and then it send the code to php